# How to use an anonymous interface callback method as parameter in C#?

Tags: c#, java, callback, unity-game-engine

In Java, I'm able to do the following:

```
Java

public class Button {
    private Callback callback;

    public Button(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void update() {
        // Check if clicked..
        callback.onClick(this);
    }

    public interface Callback {
        public void onClick(Button Button);
    }
}
```

And use it like:

```
Button b = new Button(new Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(Button b) {
        System.out.println("Clicked");
    }
});
```

And I'm wondering, if the same is possible in (Unity) C#.

Currently I have the same setup, with the correct syntax

```
C#:

public class Button {
    private Callback callback;

    public Button(Callback callback) {
        this.callback = callback;
    }

    public void Update() {
        // Check if clicked..
        callback.OnClick(this);
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void OnClick(Button button);
    }
}
```

However, when I try to do the same when creating a button,

```
Button b = new Button(new Button.Callback() {
    void OnClick(Button button) {
        Debug.Log("Clicked");
    }
});
```

I get errors like:

```
Unexpected symbol 'void'

error CS1526: A new expression requires () or [] after type

error CS8025: Parsing error
```

I've tried making the method 'virtual' or 'abstract' in the interface, or adding the 'new' keyword before void OnClick(.. when I create the button, but no luck so far.

It seems that the unexpected symbol 'void' error dissapears if I remove the '()' from 'new Button.Callback'

I would appreciate some help here.

Comment: I'm having more luck finding answers now, I didn't know it was called an inline interface. Thanks for the links too.

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do (i.e. anonymous interfaces) is not possible in C#. However, you could use `delegates` to achieve something similar,

```
public class Button {
    private Action<Button> action;

    public Button(Action<Button> action) {
        this.action = action;
    }

    public void Update() {
        // Check if clicked..
        action(this);
    }
}
```

Then,

```
Button b = new Button(delegate(Button button) { Debug.Log("Clicked"); });
```

Or using a lambda expression, which makes it look simpler,

```
Button b = new Button(button => Debug.Log("Clicked"));
```

`Action` is basically a generic type that represents a function, specifically a function with return type of `void`. Thus you can pass in existing methods as long as they comply with the signature `void Method()`. If you specify any type parameters (using the `Action<T>` syntax) you are specifying the number and types of arguments the represented function accepts, thus `Action<Button>` is a function that returns `void` and takes in a single argument of type `Button`, just like your `Callback.OnClick` method.

Instead of using an anonymous delegate or a lambda expression (e.g. like above), you can pass in a method that complies with the expected signature,

```
void OnClick(Button button)
{
     Debug.Log("Clicked");
}
```

and pass it,

```
 Button b = new Button(OnClick);
```

Comment: Is `Action` a build in class or a custom made class that handles the button clicks?

Comment: Yes, it is basically a generic type that represents a function, specifically a function with return type of `void`. Thus you can pass in existing methods as long as they comply with the signature `void Method(Button button)`

Answer (score 2):

I think all you need is to implement your interface in final class like this:

```
public class SomeClass: Callback
{
    public SomeClass()
    {
       Button b = new Button(this);
    }


    void OnClick(Button button)
    {
        Debug.Log("Clicked");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [`Event handlers:`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/edzehd2t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Maybe you want something like this:

```
public delegate void Callback(Button btn);
public class Button
{

    public event Callback Click;
    public Button(Callback callback)
    {
        Click += callback;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        // Check if clicked..
        if (Click != null)
        {
            Click(this);
        }
    }


}
```

Usage:

```
Button btn = new Button( b => Debug.Log("Clicked"));
```